# Access: How To See If An Options Radio Button Is Checked

Tags: excel, ms-access, button, vba

I have 4 "Option" radio buttons that can be checked. If they are checked by a user, then I want to insert a record into a table. Code would be something as follows...

```
If option1Button is Checked then 
     doInsertQuery
If option2Button is Checked then 
     doInsertQuery
If option3Button is Checked then 
     doInsertQuery
If option4Button is Checked then 
     doInsertQuery
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do the "is Checked" method. I'm coming from a VB.net background, and VBA definitely doesn't have the toys i'm used to having for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than querying the state of each **Option *Button***, you should instead obtain the `Value` property of the **Option *Group*** itself, i.e. the frame surrounding the set of option buttons.

This will yield the **Option Value** associated with the selected **Option Button**.

Since only one Option Button may be selected within an Option Group, I would suggest using a VBA `Select Case` statement when testing the selected value, e.g.:

```
Select Case YourFrameControl
    Case 1: Debug.Print "Option 1 Selected."
    Case 2: Debug.Print "Option 2 Selected."
    Case 3: Debug.Print "Option 3 Selected."
End Select
```

Since the `Value` property is the default value returned by a control, it needn't be explicitly stated.

---

If the Option Buttons are **standalone** and are **not** a member of an Option Group, then you can query the `Value` property of the Option Button itself, which will yield a True (`-1`) or False (`0`) value, or True (`-1`), False (`0`), or `Null` for a Triple-State Option Button.

In this case, I would suggest using **checkboxes** instead of radio buttons, since this would be more intuitive for an interface permitting selection of multiple options.

Since you state that the user may select *"all options that apply"*, you would likely need to use a sequence of separate `if` statements to evaluate an expression for each selected option.

If you are only evaluating a single expression, you could write the `if` statements in line:

```
If YourOptionControl1 Then Debug.Print "Option 1 selected."
If YourOptionControl2 Then Debug.Print "Option 2 selected."
If YourOptionControl3 Then Debug.Print "Option 3 selected."
```

Or alternatively, as separate `if` blocks:

```
If YourOptionControl1 Then
    Debug.Print "Option 1 selected."
End If
If YourOptionControl2 Then
    Debug.Print "Option 2 selected."
End If
If YourOptionControl3 Then
    Debug.Print "Option 3 selected."
End If
```

Again, since the `Value` property is the default value returned by a control, it needn't be explicitly stated; for the above, I've assumed you are **not** using triple-state option buttons.

Comment: I've done something like this in VB.Net and it was very helpful. My issue here is that multiple option buttons can be selected. Each option button stands by itself with no framecontrol. It's a "Check all that apply" thing

Comment: @Bob In that case, I would suggest using checkboxes over radio buttons, as radio buttons tend to imply that only a single option may be selected. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer above.

Comment: I completely agree, for whatever reason checkboxes weren't showing up in my controls. I'm going with them now, i'm guessing the process to checking if they're checked is similar to above?

Comment: Exactly as per the lower half of my answer, yes.

Comment: Awesome, you've been a ton of help. Answer accepted and thanks so much!